# I have created a simple entry form in java and i need to know what code is missing to update this data in oracle 11g using sql developer

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, actionlistener

How Do I add this into my Sql developer( Oracle 11G) Some of the code seems to be missing. I want to press the save button and all the data from the text fields should be saved in the database.

The code starts here for the save button action listener:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 


try {


        String sql = "insert into STUDENT(STUDENT_ID,STUDENT_FNAME,STUDENT_LNAME,USERNAME,PASWORD,ADDRESS,AGE,CNIC,NATIONALITY,CITY,) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";


        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);


        pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());


        pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());


        pst.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());


        pst.setString(4, jTextField4.getText());


        pst.setString(5, jTextField5.getText());


        pst.setString(6, jTextField6.getText());


        pst.setString(7, jTextField7.getText());


        pst.setString(8, jTextField8.getText());


        pst.setString(9, jTextField9.getText());


        pst.setString(10, jTextField10.getText());


        pst.executeUpdate(sql);

        pst.close();


    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    }
```